# C++ Assign value of class member from a different function

Tags: c++, function, class

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Test 
{
    public:
          int x = 1;
};
```

and within main I create an object of said class and call a function called setInt:

```
int main()
{
     Test example;
     setInt(example);
     std::cout << example;
}
```

```
void setInt(Test example)
{
     (// random if statement)
           example.x = 5;
}
```

This would output 1.

How would this be possible? I know in the example above the variable "example" is local to the function only, but is there a way to change the value of the variable in main()?

(Please excuse any errors in code)

Comment: You should open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use references and pointers, and there should be plenty of examples that do exactly this.

Comment: If you are learning C++ after Java or C# or another language where you only ever have reference to object, it's best that you forget everything you learned there and start anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just copying the integer and then assigning a new value but not manipulating with the original values. If you could've written:

```
void setInt(Test& example)
{
    // Now you are changing the original value here
    example.x = 5;
}
```

It could then work. There's an alternative of reference-to operator, that's called pointers. They works like references through function. When you change their values anywhere on dereference, the main value is also changed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, passing an argument to a function passes it by value, which copies the argument. Changes to this copy in the function are not reflected in `main`.

If you want to modify the argument that is passed in, you can use references. Change your signature to:

```
void setInt(Test &example) { // changing example changes the argument used in main
```

Comment: You could mention implicit value semantic in C++, the question was "why is it not working as expected?"